# Is there a plugin for Wordpress for creating 'Accounts' where all users who belong to that Account can only see Account data?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, users, user-access

Is there a plugin for something where I can group users into an 'Account' and then one particular Account is restricted to seeing only content targeted to that group (therefore a user would need to be signed in).

For instance, if I have two accounts:

- Acme Corp
- Big Inc

And then associate 3 different/unique employees as WP users to Acme Corp, 3 different/unique as WP users to Big Inc (for a total of 6 different/unique WP users) - when signed in WP users go to a particular 'Company Holiday Party' page - each one would see different things about their particular Company/Account's Holiday Party.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that a lot of membership plugins can do, e.g. MemberPress, Restrict Content Pro, or similar membership or user group plugins. Which is best for you depends on your particular setup. From what you're describing, you only need basic membership/group functionality (without features like payments), so I'd suggest going with a basic, free plugin from the WordPress.org repository, like [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/).

You can check out different solutions by searching for "memberships" or "groups".